# Why is python unable to read the yahoo finance API?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to analyze stock prices from yahoo finance but I keep running into errors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM


company = str(input('enter the company symbol '))
company = 'FB'
start = dt.datetime(2011,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)

data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1,1))
prediction_days = 60

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range (prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
  x_train.append(scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x,0])
  y_train.append(scaled_data[x,0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1],1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape =(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)

test_start=dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
test_end = dt.datetime.now()

test_data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', test_start, test_end)
actual_prices = test_data['Close'].values

total_dataset = pd.concat((data['Close'],test_data['Close']), axis=0)
model_inputs = total_dataset[len(total_dataset)- len(test_data) - prediction_days:].values
model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1,1)
model_inputs = scaler.transform(model_inputs)


x_test = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(model_inputs)):
  x_test.append(model_inputs[x-prediction_days:x,0])

x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))

predicted_prices = model.predict(x_test)
predicted_prices = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)

plt.plot(actual_prices, color = 'black', label = f"Actual{company}  price")
plt.plot(predicted_prices, color = 'green', label = f"Predicted{company}  price")
plt.title(f"{company}  share price")
plt.xlabel ('Time')
plt.ylabel(f"{company}  share price")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get the following error

```
RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/history?                
period1=1293854400&period2=1546401599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html lang="en-us"><head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n      <meta charset="utf-8">\n      
<title>Yahoo</title>\n      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial- 
scale=1,minimal-ui">\n      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n      
<style>\n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc 
url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: 
cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", 
helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      
width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border- 
spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 
400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      
font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      
*display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n               
</style>\n  <script>\n    document.write(\'<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t=\'+new 
Date().getTime()+\'&src=aws&err_url=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+\'&err=% 
<pssc>&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\')+\'" width="0px" 
height="0px"/>\');var 
beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+ne...
```

I know the API was having issues earlier but I thought it was resolved by now. Is there an alternate way to pull the data from the API?
Any suggestions on how to get around this would be appreciated.
Not sure why I keep getting this. This used to work fine a few weeks ago.
Also, I'm using GoogleColab to run this code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: one day few weeks ago there was many questions about `yfinance` and similar modules - all problem was because `Yahoo` changed HTML on pages and modules needed also changes - solution was to install the newest modules.

Comment: I see in erro `Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.` so maybe it is only temporary problem on server. Or maybe it need to instal the newest `yfinance` againg. Or maybe they have to add new changes in `yfinance` and you have to wait some time.

Comment: I test code and it work for me if I install the newest `pandas_datareader`. I have also the newest `yfinance` but I don't know if it is important.

Answer (score 0):

yahoo finance is changed to `yfinance`. So `pip install yfinance` and then you could do

```
 import yfinance as yf
 yf.pdr_override() 
 from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
 temp_df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("FB", start, end)
```

It returns a data frame `temp_df`.